# How can I convert a day, DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS +XXXX to unix time in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm working with a timestamp that is formatted `Thu, 04 Jan 2024 18:25:01 +0000` but I need it in Unix time. I've looked at several library functions and cannot figure out how I can achieve this. How can I convert this to a unix timestamp?

I looked at the different Python datetime methods and none of them would achieve my goal.

Comment: Is your "timestamp" an actual datetime data type, or is it a string? If the latter, you probably need to first convert to a true datetime, then do your unix conversion (there must be hundreds of examples of doing this).

Comment: What specifically did you try? Parsing that to a datetime is straightforward, as is getting a timestamp from that.

Comment: The format of the date you show is NOT the format specified in your title

Comment: Note that as far as I know, if your +0000 is sometimes different, such as +0100 or -0100 ... then you will probably want to convert to a timestamp and also make the adjustment to get the datetime in UTC (+0000) and then (finally) convert to your unix timestamp ... if that makes sense. Unix timestamps do not preserve a time zone so you can just think of them as being in UTC time generally speaking.

Comment: [dateutil.parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) can be very handy for converting a string to a `datetime` object.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`datetime.timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) that gives UNIX timestamp, in seconds, precision of microseconds

Use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert a string to a `datetime` object

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.now()
print(d.timestamp(), "seconds")  # 1704394088.831857 seconds

d = datetime.strptime("Thu, 04 Jan 2024 18:25:01 +0000", "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
print(d.timestamp(), "seconds")  # 1704392701.0
```

```
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(d.timestamp()))  # 2024-01-04 18:25:01
```

Comment: I think highlighting `strptime` is about as important as `timestamp` to solving this problem.